# Select duplicates by attributes in QGIS

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, duplication

I selected my duplicates in my attribute table by Count(1,"ID")>1. Now I just only want to keep the duplicates with the highest areas. Is there a way to directly select them or a work around to keep them?

[image]

Comment: I guess you could append your query by `AND NOT maximum("Area",count(1,"ID")>1)`. Though I don't know, if this exact query works - rather take it as an idea where to start.

Comment: It's not more `AND maximum("Area", "ID") = "Area"` ?

Comment: @J. Monticolo thx, your approach works fine for me.